# Disabling Woo Commerce Wordpress Tool Bar For Customers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a site that has woocommerce on. When a new customer buys from the site they create an account.

When the account is created they become a Customer (in user roles).

This is great as they have limited access, however they can view the Wordpress toolbar located above the site.

Does anyone know how i can remove this.

I've tried multiple 'displace admin toolbar' plugins and tried adding custom code to the functions file but nothing has worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this function at the end of your functions.php:

```
// Customers won't see the bar, only administrators.
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
 if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

**Source:** [WooCommerce Article](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203107607-Hide-WordPress-Admin-Bar-for-Users)

Comment: Sorry this didn't work, you can still see the banner when logged in

Answer (score 0):

While Iago's answer will remove the admin bar, they would still have access to the dashboard by typing in `site.com/wp-admin`. 
If you use the:

```
// Customers won't see the bar, only administrators.
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
 if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

along with the following:

```
if (is_admin()) 
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array('customer', $user->roles)) 
    {
        wp_redirect(get_home_url());
    }
}
```

while a customer is logged in the admin bar is hidden and if the customer tries to view the dashboard then they will be redirected to the homepage of the website.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Unfortunately it didnt work for me. i added it to the functions.php file in my theme and it still shows the toolbar to the user, it however says insufficient privileges when they try and go in. I've created a dummy user that you could test with if that'll help. website: www.artgiftedbygod.co.uk User: testuser Password: testtest

Comment: Does that user have a role set to "customer"?

Comment: Yes, customer in the user panel

Comment: I've noticed this has worked however only works when the new user logs out then logs back in again. When they sign up they instantly login but they login with the tool bar. When they log out and then in again its gone. Any ideaS?